# Integral of series expansion...

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Why is $$\int _0^1\:\left(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-....-x^{2n-1}\right)dx = \int _0^1\:\left(\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x}\right)dx,$$ why do we have $1+x$ in the denominator, and why does $1-x^{2n}$ appear in the numerator? Please explain.

Comment: Have you heard the word "geometric series"?

Comment: maybe there is series summation?

Comment: note that the integral here is not really significant :)

Comment: yes Einstein you've right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is a well known identity, I shall give a heuristic proof which is not so formalized for the sake of understanding.

Using the property of distributivity,

$(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4\ldots-x^{2n-1})(1+x)=1-x+x^2\ldots-x^{2n-1}+x-x^2+x^3-x^4+
\ldots+x^{2n-1}-x^{2n}=1-x^{2n}$

Thus, dividing by $1+x$, we have $1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots-x^{2n-1}=\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x}$

Another way to show this is using the identity

$1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Denote this sum by $S$.

$S=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots-x^{2n-1}=1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2n-2}-(x+x^3+\ldots+x^{2n-1})$

Setting y=x^2

$S=1+y+y^2+\ldots+y^{n-1}-x(1+x^2+x^4+\ldots+x^{2n-2})$

$=1+y+y^2+\ldots+y^{n-1}-x(1+y+y^2+\ldots+y^{n-1})$

$=\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}-x\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}$

$=\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}-x\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x^2}$

$=\frac{1-x^{2n}}{1-x}$ when one notes that $(1-x^2)=(1-x)(1+x)$

QED.